# Assigning dataframe columns in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

In rpy2 what is the equivalent of say:

```
dataf <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
dataf$a <- dataf$a + 1
```

Since `dataframe.rx2` is the rpy2 equivalent of `[[.dataframe` I would have thought that the answer would have been:

```
 d = {'a': robjects.IntVector((1,2,3)), 'b': robjects.IntVector((4,5,6))}
 dataf = robjects.DataFrame(d)
 dataf.rx2["a"] = dataf.rx2("a").ro + 1
```

but that gives the following error:

```
 RRuntimeError: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), "a", 2:4) : 
    argument "value" is missing, with no default
```

I also tried:

```
dataf.rx["a"] = dataf.rx("a").ro + 1
dataf[dataf.index("a")] = dataf.rx2("a").ro + 1
```

without any luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
i = dataf.colnames.index('a')
dataf[i] = dataf[i].ro + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this also works:

```
dataf.rx[True, 'a'] = dataf.rx(True, 'a').ro + 1
```

EDIT:

But this solution isn't exactly equivalent to the above solution. It works in this case, but doesn't in others.

e.g.

```
In [18]: d = {"a": ro.StrVector(["a","b","c"]), "b": ro.IntVector([1,2,3])}

In [19]: dataf = ro.DataFrame(d)

In [20]: print ro.r.levels(dataf.rx2("a"))
[1] a b c

In [21]: dataf.rx[True, "a"] = ro.r.relevel(dataf.rx2("a"), "b")

In [22]: print ro.r.levels(dataf.rx2("a"))
[1] a b c
```

where as the accepted solution does:

```
In [23]: i = dataf.colnames.index("a")

In [24]: dataf[i] = ro.r.relevel(dataf.rx2("a"), "b")

In [25]: print ro.r.levels(dataf.rx2("a"))
[1] b a c
```